# How to reference the written contents of a cell in sumIF

Tags: excel

- Any cell in column A could contain one of 500 words.
- Any cell in column B could contain any dollar value
- In each cell in column D I need to display the total value of all things sharing a particular name
- In column C, next to each given total value there needs to be the name of what was totaled

A concrete explanation:

Say I'm buying some things today

- Milk  $2.50
- Eggs  $1.50
- Milk $1.75
- Eggs $1.25

I would like something that displays

- Milk  $4.25
- Eggs  $3.75

Thank you.

Comment: This is tongue in cheek - but do you want the total for Eggs not to be equal to the sum of the individual entries?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you really want a simple pivot table. If that's not the case, then you have to do the following:

1. Create a list of unique "shopping items" in column `C` (If you don't want to use VBA for this you can follow the instructions at http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/ - warning it's pretty abstruse
2. Do a `SUMIF()` in the usual way: in cell `D2`, you might write

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$501,C2, $B$2:$B$501)
```

and copy it down to as many rows as there are entries. In the process the references to `A` and `B` remain fixed (with the `$` sign) and the reference to `C2` updates in each row. I am assuming there are 500 rows plus headers in row 1.

You could also use the Advanced Filter option to extract unique records - see for example the tutorial at http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html .